# Zurb Foundation top-bar dropdown doesn't work on hover

Tags: drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation

I built a site on Foundation framework with vanilla css and then got into Sass, so I converted site to Sass to take advantage of easy customization going forward. Unfortunately when I did, the top-bar stopped functioning properly. The dropdown no longer works on hover. I can click to get it to dropdown, but it won't automatically drop down, as expected, on hover. Anyone else having this issue?

site here: http://www.parker-gibson.com/testing/lifedesign

Thanks in advance for any insight into this problem!

Comment: It looks like your jQuery and Foundation scripts aren't where you think the are, because you're getting a 404 Not Found on both. I wouldn't think that would affect the CSS hover property, but with the mobile functionality of top-bar, it's definitely possible. I'll check on that later if I get a chance. In the meantime, I'd try fixing the 404 errors and be sure to run $(document).foundation() after your scripts load. Nice, clean site by the way!

Comment: Thanks @chrisjsherm! That was it. I'm new to Sass and my js was out of place. Rearranged files and it's now working as expected. Thanks for the compliment on the site as well!